# Is it possible a hash code of mobile number is converted in to real number i want to know mobile number from my mobile number hash code

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashcode, hashset, gethashcode

Is it possible a hash code of mobile number is converted in to real number i want to know mobile number from given mobile number hash code?Just as a testing purpose

Comment: Just as a little hint: Don't make your titles to long.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't. Hashing functions are destructive